# I cannot import reactive search

Tags: reactjs, elasticsearch, import, module

When I import reactive search from the following module:

> import {ReactiveBase} from "@appbaseio/reactivesearch";

It keeps showing me the following error:

> ./node_modules/@appbaseio/reactivecore/lib/actions/query.js
>   Module not found: Can't resolve '../../../../node_modules/@appbaseio/reactivecore/src/actions/maps' in '/Users/mattewlee/Desktop/CS/Swallaby/walkon-map-website/node_modules/@appbaseio/reactivecore/lib/actions'

Well, for sure, I have installed for sure with "npm install @appbaseio/reactivesearch "
But this doesn't seem to work. Thank you for your answer in advance.

This is the following code of 
my App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {ReactiveBase} from "@appbaseio/reactivesearch";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <section className="container">
            <ReactiveBase
                app="my_housing"
                credentials="myapikey"
                type="listing"
            >
                Hello from ReactiveSearch!
            </ReactiveBase>
        </section>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I'am having the same problem. It may be from the node module it self

Comment: @yacinebenzmane That's what I thought so too :( But let's try be patient until someone answers bud : )

Comment: Are you also doing the scotch.io tutorial?